# Is there a way to set a minimum amount of checkboxes needed to be checked in a group?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;" class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_1" class="chk-col-teal" name="d1[0]" value="1" />
        <label for="md_checkbox_1">walking</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_2" class="chk-col-teal" name="d1[1]" value="1" />
    <label for="md_checkbox_2">public commute (land/ water)</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_3" class="chk-col-teal" name="d1[2]" value="1" />
    <label for="md_checkbox_3">family-owned vehicle</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_4" class="chk-col-teal" name="d1[3]" value="1"/>
    <label for="md_checkbox_4">school service</label>
</div>
```

How can I make it so it is required to click at least 1 checkbox in the group?

Comment: Can you post your PHP or JavaScript please? (How have you tried to ensure at least one box is checked? - Where did you get stuck with it?

Comment: @Stuart oof... I already removed my previous unsuccessful code...

Comment: Are you trying this in JS or PHP?

Comment: @Stuart Javascript, but as long as there's a way in php, I'll take it

Comment: Well surely the first thing you would try, is to ensure that the `count()` of your `POST`ed `d1`'s, is at least 1, no?

Comment: @Stuart ok, I'll try that